# Why isn't my authentication cookie being set in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've got an MVC4 project that I'm working on. When a user's login credentials are valid, I call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` to indicate that the user is logged in. (I have it wrapped in a class so I can mock the Interface for my unit tests.)

```
namespace FlashMercy.Shared.Security
{
    using System;
    using System.Web.Security;

    public class Auth : IAuth
    {
        public void SetAuthCookie(string userId, bool remember)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId, remember);
        }

        public void Signout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
    }
}
```

In the debugger, I can confirm that the `.SetAuthCookie(userId, remember)` line is executing, and `userId` *is* populated.

Then, I have a custom authorize attribute to check that the user is logged in:

```
namespace FlashMercy.Shared.Security
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class FlashMercyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the application, the `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false` even after I've supposedly set the auth cookie. Also, `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` is empty. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

### Update

If you care to look at the whole source, it's available on GitHub: https://github.com/quakkels/flashmercy.

Comment: When your Auth class is executed? If it executed after response send to client e.g. Redirect, then Cookie won't be set to client. You need to check in browser, does cookie exists in response to your Login page

Comment: (using Chrome) When I look at the list of cookies in browser, I see 2.  The first one is .ASPXAUTH and the other is ASP.NET_SessionId. Both are set on the localhost domain.

Comment: Ok, can you check in your `FlashMercy` attribute - `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies`. Are there any cookies in it? Especially `.ASPXAUTH` as authentication info is stored in it.

Comment: Yes... Both are there in the Cookies collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is that you are using FormsAuthentication, but you didn't add it to web.config. Your web.config should have such section:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Based on this Mode Asp.Net understand what authentication mode it should use, e.g. Forms, Windows, etc. And without settings it to `Forms` value -  `FormsAuthenticationModule` just ignores .ASPXAUTH cookie from the request.

PS. I've downloaded your code, and with correct authentication section in web.config it works fine and updates `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to true.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Forgot about that piece.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only set the authentication cookie but do not have anything that load it.

It's forms authentication that uses that cookie. So you either have to activate forms authentication or you'll have to load it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false even after I've supposedly set the auth cookie.

This will always be the case if you do *not* redirect after `SetAuthCookie()`.  The ASP.Net pipeline is in charge of authorizing the user (most of the time before we write code) in the `AuthenticateRequest`.  Setting a Cookie does not update the current `User.Identity`, this requires code that has already been executed.  Just make sure anytime you `SetAuthCookie()` you immediately redirect (server side is fine) to another URL (probably should anyway, its a good way to seperate logging in a user, and what they should do next [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).